# SQL query for large data filter from big database

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, rdbms

I have a large database on server. The database is all about the mobile numbers with about 20 millions of records at present. I want to match the mobile numbers on my website to filter the DND or Non-DND mobile numbers. I am using this query for small number filtering

```
SELECT phone_number
FROM mobnum_table
WHERE phone_number IN ('7710450282', '76100003451', '8910003402', '9410009850', '7610000191');
```

But what about in the condition I want to filter 1,00,000 mobile number records in few seconds..? **I heard about SQL query optimization but not aware so much about it. Also please guide me what storage engine should I consider in this situation?**

I have already googled it, but didn't find so much good answer for the same.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using, particularly for questions about optimization (which might be very database specific).

Comment: I am using My SQL for the database

Comment: Put the numbers in another table, then use a join?  That way you can bulk load the table too.

Comment: What do you mean filter by 1,000,000 records? Would that be something like 1 million numbers inside the () in the where clause? If so, you might consider having a second table with the numbers you want to filter against, and do a join with that table.

Comment: @JD_bravo - if will be really useful if you provide some more info.

Comment: What are you going to do with the 1,000,000 records when they are returned?  In all likelihood, you can do more work in the database, and issue a more succinct query.

Comment: That may be 1 lakh, not 1 million.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mobnum_table`.

Comment: Condition is that the number which one needed to match with database table is coming from a html page field where visitor will come and put the 10,000 numbers their and after click submit (SCRUB IT) it will be matched with database table of mobile numbers. Pls visit 97.74.37.64 here for more better understanding. Just put upto 15000 mobile numbers in this and see how much time it is taking.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem in your requirement itself. If you tell us more about your problem, may be we can help you. Anyway its not a good idea to give all the 100000 numbers in `IN`. One option is to create another table and do an inner join.

Assume you have another table `selectednumbers` with columns `id` and `phone_number`, 
you can do an inner join as follows

```
SELECT phone_number FROM mobnum_table a inner join selectednumbers b on 
a.phone_number=b.phone_number
```

As I mentioned earlier, your question is not complete. So kindly provide some more information so we can give optimized query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But the condition is that the number which one needed to match is coming from a html page field where visitor will come and put the 10000 numbers their and after click submit it will be matched with database table mobile numbers pls visit http://97.74.37.64/ here for more better understanding.  Just put upto 15000 mobile numbers in this and see how much time it is taking.

Comment: Also remember the above link is of my client not mine.

Comment: @JD_bravo - So you will collect lots of numbers from user and you want to compare those numbers with numbers in database right?

Comment: yes.. and also want to filter the numbers those are matched and those are not matched separate..

Answer (score 0):

So you're generating a list of 100,000 numbers, and then putting that back into another query?

If you're getting the numbers from a table, take the query that generated the list of numbers in the first place, put it inside the in() brackets, and you'll see a large improvement immediately.

Restructure them both to use a JOIN, instead of in() and you'll see even more.

OR, depending on your DB structure, just do

```
SELECT phone_number
FROM mobnum_table
WHERE DND = 1
```